# How to give access to a group of users after refreshing a salesforce sandbox?

Tags: salesforce, sandbox, tooling

I would like a group of users to have access to a sandbox after it has been refreshed without manually activating them.

From my understanding this should be possible after the spring '23 release with the introduction of the field *ActivationUserGroupId* on the [SandboxInfo object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm).

When I try to refresh the sandbox using the tooling API I get this error

```json
[
    { 
        "message": "No such column 'ActivationUserGroupId' on sobject of type SandboxInfo",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_FIELD"
    }
]
```

I'm requesting for a refresh using `{{_endpoint}}/services/data/v57.0/tooling/sobjects/SandboxInfo/{{sandbox_id}}` where *{{_endpoint}}* is the production org's endpoint and *{{sandbox_id}}* is the id of the sandbox to refresh. The payload of the request is as follows

```
{
    "LicenseType": "DEVELOPER_PRO",
    "AutoActivate": true,
    "ActivationUserGroupId": "{{group_id}}"
}
```

where the *{{group_id}}* is the id of the group in production which should get access to the sandbox after refresh.

If I remove the *ActivationUserGroupId* attribute in the body the request works. However, then the group of users does not get access.

PS: The production org is running release spring '23. However, when using the tooling API v57.0 to describe the SandboxInfo object there is no field named ActivationUserGroupId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the `ActivationUserGroupId` using `SandboxInfo` and confirmed this is now working. My requests are made with API v57.0.

```
    sandbox_data = {
        'LicenseType': 'DEVELOPER',
        'SandboxName': sandbox_name,
        'ActivationUserGroupId': 'group_ID'
    }
```